# ~/virtualenvs/venv instead of ./venv

Tags: python, virtualenv, project, virtualenvwrapper

I am in a team programmers. I integrated `virtualenvwrapper`, since I am working on several projects. In my team project, they take into account that the virtualenv is located directly in the project. Hence, they are many files where the path is directly `./venv/bin/python`, and my supervisor didn't want to customize it. My virtualenv on that project is located in `~/.virtualenvs`. Is there a clever idea to link `./venv/bin/python` to `~/.virtualenvs/bin/python` without changing the nature of the files? To be clear, the path of my virtual is `~/virtualenvs/venv` instead of `./venv`. It works well if I write `ln -s ~/virtualenvs/venv ./venv`, but it is not clean to do such things. That's why I wanted something clean.

**Update**

I have a shell command and it works perfectly well.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~
cd ./Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/
workon venv
```

I have a management command named `reboot-db-local`

```
#!/bin/bash

source .mysql-context \
&& mysql -u $MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "DROP DATABASE credit24h_dev;" \
&& mysql -u $MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE credit24h_dev CHARSET=utf8;" \
&& ./venv/bin/python manage.py migrate \
&& ./load-fixtures \
&& ./venv/bin/python manage.py check_permissions
```

Comment: Something wrong if the project is expecting *any* specific virtualenv path. Where is this causing a problem? Where exactly are the paths hard-coded?

Comment: I would just not bother using virtualenvwrapper and use a shell function instead to load the virtualenv based on the location. That's actually much nicer than having to do `workon whatever` all the time.

Comment: Ok the full path of the virtualenv is `~/Projects/Work_Projects/credit-24-django/venv`

Comment: you can symlink ./venv to ~/your/path/to/venv but I suggest to find a new job 
 anyway:)

Comment: @DanielRoseman What do you mean?

Comment: Is this project referencing the venv folder in its shebang statement (analogous to `#!/path/to/project/venv/bin/python`), or is it hard-coded somewhere in actual code?  (Both are bad practices, by the way.)

Comment: @Makoto I will give you an example in my question. Keep it up!